# List Laravel table names without knowing database name

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

This code works fine for a specific MySQL database whose name is literally 'db_name':

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
$tables = DB::select('SHOW TABLES');
foreach($tables as $table) {
  echo $table->Tables_in_impact . '<br>';
}
```

But I don't know the database name at the time I write the code. I can pick up the database name from Laravel's `.env` file as `env('DB_DATABASE')` but I can't figure out how to work that expression into the code above.

I tried many different approaches using `eval()` but couldn't make it work. Is there a better approach than `eval()`?

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. This works:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
$key = 'Tables_in_' . env('DB_DATABASE') ;
$tables = DB::select('SHOW TABLES');
foreach($tables as $table) {
    echo $table->$key . '<br>';
}
```